# Post message on facebook wall in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am using this code to send message on wall on my facebook:

```
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ShareOnFacebook extends Activity{


    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream"};

    private static final String TOKEN = "access_token";
        private static final String EXPIRES = "expires_in";
        private static final String KEY = "facebook-credentials";

    private Facebook facebook;
    private String messageToPost;

    public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
            Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
            editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
            return editor.commit();
        }

        public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
            facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
            return facebook.isSessionValid();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        facebook = new Facebook(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
        restoreCredentials(facebook);


        setContentView(R.layout.facebook_dialog);

        String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("facebookMessage");
        if (facebookMessage == null){
            facebookMessage = "Test wall post";
        }
        messageToPost = facebookMessage;
        if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            loginAndPostToWall();
            finish();
        }
        else {
            postToWall(messageToPost);
        }
    }



    public void loginAndPostToWall(){
         facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
    }

    public void postToWall(String message) {
        FacebookPoster fp = new FacebookPoster();
        fp.execute(message, null, null);
        }
        private class FacebookPoster extends AsyncTask {

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        showToast(result);
        finish();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", "Test");
            parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
            try {
            facebook.request("me");
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("")
            || response.equals("false")) {
            return "Blank response.";
            } else {
            return "Message posted to your facebook wall!";
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ShareOnFacebook" , e.getMessage());
            return "Failed to post to wall!";
            }
        }
        }
    class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            saveCredentials(facebook);
            if (messageToPost != null){
            postToWall(messageToPost);
        }
        }
        public void onCancel() {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
            finish();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();

        }
        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();

        }
    }

    private void showToast(String message){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

but something is wrong, because:
1) I can't see my post on my wall.
2) When I click again to send post I need again login.
How I can resolve my problems?

Comment: First check if you have any active sessions and logged in user, if not you have to log your user, save the session and after that post the message on your wall.

Comment: how can I do that? Can you give any example?

Comment: I get something like that in logs: {Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[email]},}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you gone through    http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/ this in this there declared seperate method 
and another important thing is go through credentials concept in fb integration for logging out.